# Python random generating identical matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that when run produces identical matrices but I want it to generate a different matrix each time.

I believe there is a problem with the sample method from random but am unsure on how to fix it. I also tried creating a random object and using sample with that but it had the same effect.

The aim of the createIndividual function is to take the grid given and fill each row with a permutation of 1-9, however the rows come with some pre-fixed values that should not be repeated. This function works. However when calling it multiple times with the createPopulation function it returns identical matrices each time when I want each one to be unique.

```
from random import sample

POPULATION_SIZE = 10

prefill = [[4,0,0,1,0,2,6,3,0],
           [5,0,0,6,4,3,8,0,0],
           [7,6,0,5,0,8,4,1,2],
           [6,0,0,0,0,9,3,4,8],
           [2,4,0,8,3,0,9,5,0],
           [8,0,9,4,1,5,0,7,0],
           [0,7,2,0,0,4,0,6,0],
           [0,5,4,2,0,0,0,8,9],
           [0,8,6,3,0,7,1,2,4]]

def createPopulation(grid):
    result = []
    for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE):
        result.append(createIndividual(grid))
    return result

def createIndividual(grid):
  '''
  Populates each row with random permuations from 1-9 avoiding duplicates.
  '''
  for i in range(len(grid)):
    permutation = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    temp = set()
    for j in range(len(grid)): # Remove pre existing
      if grid[i][j] != 0:
        permutation.remove(grid[i][j])
        temp.add(j)
    for j in range(len(grid)): # Randomly fill in blanks
      if grid[i][j] == 0:
        n = sample(permutation, 1)[0]
        permutation.remove(n)
        grid[i][j] = n

  return grid

pop = createPopulation(prefill)
for i in pop:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @TomKarzes That is normally not necessary.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think you're right - I removed my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in `createIndividual` function. It has side effects, i.e. it modifies the original `prefill` matrix. Therefore, in first run, it correctly fills the gaps and returns a matrix but at the same time it changes the original `prefill`. In all the subsequent calls, it returns `prefixl` as is, because it has no gaps anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Check out random.shuffle
https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

It will randomly reorder a list, you won't get duplicates since it's a reordering.

```
prefill = [[4,0,0,1,0,2,6,3,0],
       [5,0,0,6,4,3,8,0,0],
       [7,6,0,5,0,8,4,1,2],
       [6,0,0,0,0,9,3,4,8],
       [2,4,0,8,3,0,9,5,0],
       [8,0,9,4,1,5,0,7,0],
       [0,7,2,0,0,4,0,6,0],
       [0,5,4,2,0,0,0,8,9],
       [0,8,6,3,0,7,1,2,4]]
for row in prefill:
  random.shuffle(row)
```

Note that it'll shuffle them in place though so a function to create a new matrix each time would look like:

```
def create_random_square_matrix(size):
  matrix = []
  values = range(1, size + 1)
  for i in range(size):
    row = list(values)
    random.shuffle(row)
    matrix.append(row)
  return matrix

nine_by_nine = create_random_square_matrix(9)
```